# Can Buddhism help me find my passion?

Tags: the-buddha, meditation-insight, lay-buddhism, meditation-recommendation, meditation-effects

I have been trying to find my passion for last many years, to be honest I do not even know how should I try to find my passion.
Though I have been practicing meditation for last couple of years (not punctually though), but I think meditation doesn't help me find my passion.

If any one have read "POSITIVE PSYCHOLOGY - HAPPIER BY TAL BEN-SHAHAR"
In short the book talks about 4 type of Burger:

1 RATRACE: means those who eats a vegetarian normal burger and suffer for anticipated gain in future, which never happens.

2 NIHILISM: This burger is both bad in taste and not even good for health, means worst living style.

3 HEDONISM: This burger is only tasty but not good enough for health means i like watching videos on YouTube but it doesn't have any future.

4 HAPPINESS: This burger is both tasty and good for health means one loves doing something and also have a bright impact on future.

So everyone want to eat the 4th burger, Can anyone help me find.

Comment: down vote ? anger hatred rises, watching it feels better :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "passion" you talk about sounds like a craving for something which you haven't defined. Your question seems to be asking, "I crave something (I crave something to feel passionate about), but I don't know how to find the object of my craving. Can Buddhism tell me how to find what I crave?"

I think that basic Buddhism teaches one to recognize that "craving" as the source of dissatisfaction.

If your craving were for the sense-pleasure or the feeling-pleasure of an addictive drug (cocaine for example), I think that Buddhism would recommend that you seek *less* of it rather than seeking more.

The "happiness" you mention at the end sounds to me like it might be [Sukha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukha). I think there are several sources of sukha (i.e. several conditions, several types of activity which condition sukha), for example such as listed in the [Pali literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukha#Pali_literature) section of that Wikipedia article.

Someone once lent me a book, titled *The Buddha's Teachings to Laypeople: Practical Advice for Prosperity and Lasting Happiness*, which I recommend. It organizes, summarizes, and references suttas which contain practical advice for laypeople. There are a lot of them! It has various chapters: about earning, saving, and spending money; having good relationships with people; making good decisions; and so on.

Comment: I have ordered the book as soon as you posted the answer, today i will receive the book, If i have any query in the book, i will ask a question and hope you will help, Thanks @ChrisW

Answer (score 4):

Usual disclaimer - this is a Zen answer, not a Vipassana answer.

The short answer is yes, but I think the reasons for me saying so may disappoint you.  It's basic Buddhism to say that our dissatisfaction in life comes from craving.  I agree with ChrisW in that I think the passion you are seeking is just another manifestation of that craving.  That is not a slight against you.  The Buddha was not stating the obvious when he first declared the noble truths.  After almost 2,500 years, it's pretty obvious that people still haven't caught on.

What Buddhism offers - especially in the way of meditation practice - is another way of engaging the world.  We often see our lives as an unfolding narrative.  We imagine the characters who come into it and the events that transpire to be a meaningful, cohesive story.  We add further artifice when we throw our expectations into the mix and think things like "I must find a passion in my life!", "such and such must happen by the time I'm 40!", "I want to be such and such kind of person!", etc. According to Buddhism (specifically Zen), these expectations are a source of immense unhappiness; our belief that life has a sense of narrative cohesiveness is also a complete illusion.  Rather than searching for something or expecting our life to play out in a predetermined way, our practice asks that we simply sit and watch it unfold without forcing it.  I think it's profoundly presumptuous to believe that we can forge a better life for ourselves than that which grows naturally simply from our wholehearted being in the world.  We miss so much happiness when we try to force the world to conform to our expectations.  We set ourselves up for misery when we try to *become* the people we think we ought to be.  The way of Buddhism is to be what Christian author C.S. Lewis calls "surprised by joy".  Don't look for it; it will find you.

Meditation practice develops that hands-off approach to living in microcosm.  It equips us with the tools to just be with the universe.  Rather than relying on desire and expectation to reveal a passion to you, sit down on the cushion and let it come all on its own.  If it never appears, who cares?  At the end of a life of sincere practice, the wisdom you find and the joy you discover unexpectedly will more than make up for it.

Comment: +1 Up-vote for this answer, But if one do not crave for more money or crave for Nirvana, How can one get there.
More over I honestly do not want to sit on this chair and code for rest of my life.
Kindly explain.

Comment: LMAO!  Sit - as on a cushion!  :-P  And let's use a metaphor from baseball.  Obviously, you can't just stand at the plate.  You're there to get on base.  If you swing at everything he throws and try to force the issue, you aren't very likely to get a hit.  Most likely you ground or strike out.  The best hitters in baseball swing at the best pitches.  If their pitch doesn't show up, they don't swing.  When it does, the put everything into it.  You've just got to wait for your pitch.  And even if everything life throws is lousy, if you practice, you'll still walk to first after four pitches.

Comment: I still having trouble getting the essence out of it, But I have purchased "The Buddha's Teachings to Laypeople: Practical Advice for Prosperity and Lasting Happiness" which is recommended by Chris in accepted answer, I have start reading it and find out that what Sutta's were actually suggested by Buddha to layman were mixed and this book will help me find what Buddha has to offer for layman's life

Comment: Sounds good! :-)